# How can I search BETWEEN DATES using sqlite and this Cordova plugin: cordova-sqlite-ext

Tags: sqlite, date, cordova

I was using the cordova-sqlite-ext (https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ext) plugin for cordova developments, works really nice but now I need to create a query that looks for records between two dates. I tried:

```
var my_query= "SELECT * FROM historial WHERE my_date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY id DESC";
var my_query= "SELECT * FROM historial WHERE my_date>= ? AND my_date <= ? ORDER BY id DESC";
```

But these queries return zero records altough I used a pre-populated database. How can I create the queries to achieve this?
my_date contains values like: '2020-01-31'

Thank you all.

PS: I used pre-populated databases with this plugin before with no problem at all.

Comment: What strings are you binding to those parameters in your queries?

Comment: Have you tried: `strftime('%s', my_date) >= ?`

Comment: what datatype did you use for the dates in the database?

Comment: Your queries are syntactically correct and the dates have the correct format for SQLite. So you must check the documentation of the plugin that you use.

Comment: Shawn, Im binding dates as strings for the parameters, ie '2020-05-05'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tested my code in some old phones and saw that is working fine, it seems that this issue appears since Android 6.0.1
Ill work in a solution for this.

I hope this info would be useful for someone :(

Thank you all.